# Pointwise a.e. formulation of parabolic PDE, what if null set depends on test function?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory

Let $u \in L^2(0,T;V)$ with $u_t \in L^2(0,T;V^*)$ be a solution of
$$\langle u_t(t), v \rangle + a(t;u(t), v) = \langle f(t), v \rangle$$
where $f \in L^2(0,T;V^*)$ and we have the usual assumptions on $V$ and $a$ (i.e. $V \subset H \subset V^*$ forms a Gelfand triple and $a(t;.,.)$ is a bilinear form associated to some elliptic coercive linear operator).

Now this equality holds almost everywhere for all $v$, i.e., for all $v \in V$ and all $t \in [0,T]/Z$ where $Z$ is a set of measure zero which does not depend on $v$ (see Zeidler).

What happens if the null set were to depend on $v$? Does anything go wrong?  I read the thread [Null sets in PDE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140950/null-sets-in-pde) but it didn't answer this question.

Comment: I'm confused; can you clarify how this question is different from [Null sets in PDE](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182279/pointwise-a-e-formulation-of-parabolic-pde-what-if-null-set-depends-on-test-fu)?  Also, can you elaborate on "the usual assumptions"?

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited to include the assumptions. The thread is similar (the variational formulation is slightly different) and it seems to me (if I understood) that there is not a satisfactory answer to that question. I think it important to get a definitive understanding of this because it is overlooked often.